# How to fix the problem of Google Now？

Tags: google-now

I am using nexus5  with android 5.0. But in fact i cannot use the Google now service that says that network error. I had already search about this problem,  but no one can really solve it? Does any one know how to fix it?

Comment: Does it work on WiFi?

Comment: @KaranRajBaruah no，in any connections

Comment: Is Google by any chance blocked by your internet provider?

Comment: @AndrewT. it is right。 but ihad already a Vpn service before use google and it is gobal vpn and ican visit any google sites

Comment: Could you connect to Google using their apps? (e.g. Play Store, Google+, GMail, Maps). You should update your question by mentioning the VPN. Last time I had a problem accessing Google Play Store with VPN.

Comment: all was well,it was working fine and suddenly it stopped working.sign-in error.nothing could fx.no booting, force stopping, nothing..nada

Answer (score 2):

Try this go into settings/apps/under the "ALL" tab scroll and tap on google app/ force stop, and clear cache. power you device off and back on. Test and you should be good to go.